# Showing an Activity or View Over a ListIem

Tags: c#, android, android-activity, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm trying to add an overlay to a ListItem in an Xamarin Android ListView control.  I was able to easily achieve this in iOS and made it appear like the following, in normal view:

[image: Normal TableView Item Appearance]

And then when you click on the item:

[image]

It shows an overlay with additional images (which is actually a UIViewController).  I was wondering if it's possible to do the same within Android; I would like to keep the same UI WITHOUT using a dialog, which is what all of the responses seem to indicate so far.  Seems like it should be possible...  Any ideas how to do it with an Activity (I need an activity to respond to the events within the UI as well).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, then this is what you're looking for: https://github.com/flavienlaurent/poppyview

Comment: Mine overlays the item at the current position, but that might work too... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement Quick Actions for  this purpose. Quick Actions are not provided in the Android SDK
You can find lots of examples on how to create them. Such as [here](http://lchandara.wordpress.com/2011/12/23/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) and [here](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/).

Although these are not in Xamarin, they can help u in creating them.